# Merging and splitting large PDF documents?

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

We are using [Aspose tools for .Net](http://www.aspose.com/products/total) for PDF manipulation. We have 1000+ pdf documents that needs to merge and then split them again. The merge process will add a separator page between two pdf documents while merging. So that splitting process will know where to split the document.

These 1000 documents consist of 3 different types. So i need to create 3 different separator (one for each type). The merge process will add appropriate separator while merging depending on the document type.

I know how to merge & split PDF documents using Aspose. My question is, how do i create & detect this separator page?

One option i was thinking is to create a PDF page with specific barcode and the splitting process will read the barcode. ([Using Aspose Barcode](http://www.aspose.com/products/barcode)) But this seems like time consuming process because splitting process has to read every page, check if has barcode and if true, then extract the data to check the type.

Is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share some information regarding different types of separators you are using while merging documents (*a sample document or image is greatly appreciated*).
In case you add blank pages as separators, Aspose.Pdf for .NET provides the feature to determine blank pages inside PDF file. But still when using this approach, you need to traverse through all pages and identify the blank pages.Or, you can also keep track of index where separator is being added and when you need to split, use same information.

```
// The path to the documents directory.
string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_AsposePdfFacades_TechnicalArticles();

// Instantiate a memoryStream object to hold the extracted text from Document
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
// Instantiate PdfExtractor object
PdfExtractor extractor = new PdfExtractor();

// Bind the input PDF document to extractor
extractor.BindPdf(dataDir + "FilledForm.pdf");
// Extract text from the input PDF document
extractor.ExtractText();

bool containsText = false;
bool containsImage = false;
// Save the extracted text to a text file
extractor.GetText(ms);
// Check if the MemoryStream length is greater than or equal to 1
if (ms.Length >= 1)
containsText = true;

// Extract images from the input PDF document
extractor.ExtractImage();

// Calling HasNextImage method in while loop. When images will finish, loop will exit
if (extractor.HasNextImage())
containsImage = true;

// Now find out whether this PDF is text only or image only
if (containsText == true && containsImage == false)
Console.WriteLine("PDF contains text only");
else if (containsText == false && containsImage == true)
Console.WriteLine("PDF contains image only");
else if (containsText == true && containsImage == true)
Console.WriteLine("PDF contains both text and image");
else if (containsText == false && containsImage == false)
Console.WriteLine("PDF contains neither text or nor image");
```

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: i solved my problem by using Barcode page as separator. We use Aspose BarCode to detect if its separator page. Yes we do have to loop though all the pages